# Запуск android приложений через виртуальное устройство

Tags: android, android-studio

При попытке запустить проект через виртуальное устройство, выдаёт ошибку `You CPU does not support VT-x`. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ запускать проект или это невозможно на данном процессоре?

Comment: На каком данном процессоре?

Comment: на котором запускаю и выдает ошибку, что не поддерживает. Intel Pentium B960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш процессор не поддерживает технологию аппаратной виртуализации Intel VT-x или она не включена в BIOS материнской платы.

Если процессор вообще не поддерживает эту технологию, то вы не можете использовать для эмулятора образы Intel x86/64 , только образы ARM, но работать они будут довольно медленно. Так же вы можете использовать сторонние эмуляторы, как Genymotion, они будут работать с приемлемой скоростью.

Если процессор поддерживает данную технологию, то ее необходимо включить в BIOS.
Так же необходимо установить драйвер Intel HAXM